# Store empty numpy array in h5py

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I'd like to write some data to a HDF5 file (since I have huge datasets and was told that HDF5 works well with those kinds of things).

I have a Python 2.7 dictionary with some values and some numpy arrays. What I'd like to do is simply dump that dictionary into the HDF5. No groups or whatever, just put the key-value pairs into the HDF5.

However, using h5py, if I write an empty array (or list) into the file, I get:

```
>>> file["test"] = np.array([])
ValueError: zero sized dimension for non-unlimited dimension (Invalid arguments to routine: Bad value)
```

I can't believe that HDF5 wouldn't allow me to put empty arrays into it. It just so happens that sometimes my list is empty. Can't help it.

What am I missing?

Thanks :-)

Comment: This seems to work fine for me (using h5py v2.2.1). The bigger question in my mind, though, is *why* you would want to do this. Note that if you initialize the array in this way, its `maxshape` attribute will be `(0,)`, so it will be impossible to increase its size in any dimension in order to actually store anything in it. If you want to create a dataset that can be resized to accommodate some actual data, I would create it using `file.create_dataset(..., maxshape=shape, ...)`, where `shape` is a tuple containing the maximum size of the array in each dimension.

Comment: I don't intend to change the data later on, it should just serve as data dump. But it's interesting that it works for you, I'll check my numpy version later.

Comment: Your version of h5py is much more likely to be relevant

Comment: @ali_m : That's it. Seems like h5py v2.0.0 didn't support empty arrays yet. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, arrays with size-zero dimensions are not supported in h5py  2.0.0. As far as I can tell, this feature seems to have been added in [this pull request](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/pull/334).

Comment: That pull request is about slicing. I got the same error with h5py 2.5.0 with an empty list, but I couldn't create an MWE.

Comment: @SeppoEnarvi It seemed likely to be either that PR or an earlier one, since the comments mentioned that it addressed a bunch of other issues relating to zero-size array dimensions, and it also adds a unittest that involves creating a zero-sized array. Having said that, I can't seem to reproduce the OP's error even with v2.0.0, so if you can come up with a MWE then by all means ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use (it might be unnecessary for you since you don't require groups but you might change you mind):

```
def save_group(outfile, d, group):
    with h5py.File(outfile, 'a') as g:
        for key in d:
            value = d[key]
            try:
                group.require_dataset(key, value.shape, value.dtype)
            except TypeError as e:
                del group[key]
                group.create_dataset(key, value.shape, value.dtype)
            group[key][...] = value
    return
```

To get rid of the group parameter:

```
group = g.require_group('/')
```